# Cómo conseguir esta agrupacion multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, agrupación

alguien me puede guiar en lo siguiente por favor, hace rato que me peleo con las agrupaciones y no sé cómo enfocarlo correctamente.
Tengo un albarán, las líneas de este se componen de varios articulos, estos pueden ser de diversas tallas y colores ejemplo

```
ARTICULO    DEFINICION  UNIDADES    COLOR   TALLA
art01       Art 01      1           1         31
art01       Art 01      2           1         34
art01       Art 01      3           2         32
art01       Art 01      2           3         32
art01       Art 01      1           3         35
art01       Art 01      2           1         31
art01       Art 01      1           1         32
art01       Art 01      2           1         34
art01       Art 01      2           3         31
art01       Art 01      3           3         32
art01       Art 01      2           3         34
art02       Art 02      2           1         31
art02       Art 02      6           1         33
art02       Art 02      2           1         34
art02       Art 02      8           4         31
art02       Art 02      2           4         32
art02       Art 02      4           2         31
art02       Art 02      4           2         33
art02       Art 02      2           2         34
art03       Art 03      1           1         31
art03       Art 03      3           2         33
```

Y necesito hacer una consulta que me retorne esto:

```
ARTICULO    DEFINICION  COLOR   TALLA 31    TALLA 32    TALLA 33    TALLA 34    UNIDADES
art01       Art 01      rojo        1           4                       2          7
art02       Art 02      azul                    3           2           1          6
```

Las tallas siempre son las mismas, pero no se me ocurre como usar agrupaciones para conseguir esto con una cosulta, si es que se puede.
¿Podéis echarme un cable por favor?

Comment: busca sobre tablas pivotantes...

Comment: Aunque en esta ocasión no era necesario lo que proponías, te lo agradezco, ya que el propósito de la consulta era aprender y desconocía las tablas pivotantes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si las tallas son siempre las mismas, esto lo puedes lograr con un simple `CASE` (voy a asumir que el color viene ya con el detalle):

```
SELECT
    Articulo,
    Definicion,
    Color,
    [Talla 31] = SUM(CASE WHEN Talla = 31 THEN Unidades END),
    [Talla 32] = SUM(CASE WHEN Talla = 32 THEN Unidades END),
    [Talla 33] = SUM(CASE WHEN Talla = 33 THEN Unidades END),
    [Talla 34] = SUM(CASE WHEN Talla = 34 THEN Unidades END),
    Unidades = SUM(Unidades)
FROM dbo.TuTabla
GROUP BY 
    Articulo,
    Definicion,
    Color
;
```

Comment: Vaya, me lo has dado echo, muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server soporta realizar consultas **pivote**, utilizando la cláusula [`pivot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) de la sentencia `select`.

Una consulta pivote es aquella que *gira* el resultado de la consulta en función a los valores únicos de una columna, para convertirlos en varias columnas, que es lo que buscas.

Puedes lograr el resultado con esta consulta:

```
select   Articulo
       , Color
       , [31] Talla31
       , [32] Talla32
       , [33] Talla33
       , [34] Talla34
  from (select *
          from MiTabla
       ) as fuente
pivot (    sum(unidades)
       for talla in ([31], [32], [33], [34])
      ) as pivote
```

Que, con tus datos de ejemplo, devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Articulo Color       Talla31     Talla32     Talla33     Talla34
-------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
art01    1           3           1           NULL        4
art01    2           NULL        3           NULL        NULL
art01    3           2           5           NULL        2
art02    1           2           NULL        6           2
art02    2           4           NULL        4           2
art02    4           8           2           NULL        NULL
art03    1           1           NULL        NULL        NULL
art03    2           NULL        NULL        3           NULL

(8 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-09-07T11:04:03.4350664-06:00
```

Se puede simplificar aún más si no quires nombres especiales en las columnas, por ejemplo:

```
select   *
  from MiTabla 
pivot (    sum(unidades)
       for talla in ([31], [32], [33], [34])
      ) as pivote
```

Que devuelve

```
ARTICULO DEFINICION COLOR       31          32          33          34
-------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
art01    Art 01     1           3           1           NULL        4
art01    Art 01     2           NULL        3           NULL        NULL
art01    Art 01     3           2           5           NULL        2
art02    Art 02     1           2           NULL        6           2
art02    Art 02     2           4           NULL        4           2
art02    Art 02     4           8           2           NULL        NULL
art03    Art 03     1           1           NULL        NULL        NULL
art03    Art 03     2           NULL        NULL        3           NULL

(8 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-09-07T11:31:12.0880385-06:00
```